# If Load javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mvc, razor

Eu tenho um seguinte script. São dois checkbox que funcionarão como dois radios buttons, o que acontece comigo, quando eu clico em um checkbox ele desabilita todas as questões do formulário e também desabilita o checkbox que não foi selecionado, e quando eu salvo o meu formulário e volto nele, o checkbox que selecionei está clicado normal, mais todas as questões do meu formulário não estão desabilitadas. Poderiam me ajudar?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Eventos();

  $('[name="dtd1nrob"]').change(function() {
    verificaCamposExibirOcultar4();
  });

  $('[name="dtd1nrob"]').change(function() {
    verificaCamposExibirOcultar5();
  });
});

function Eventos() {
  verificaCamposExibirOcultar4();
  verificaCamposExibirOcultar5();
};

function verificaCamposExibirOcultar4() {
  var value = $('[name="dtd1nrob"]:checked').val();
  if (value == '1') {
    $('#dtd1nrob2').prop('disabled', true).attr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#dtd1nrob2').prop('disabled', false).attr('disabled');
  }
}

function verificaCamposExibirOcultar5() {
  var value = $('[name="dtd1nrob"]:checked').val();
  if (value == '2') {
    $('#dtd1nrob1').prop('disabled', true).attr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#dtd1nrob1').prop('disabled', false).attr('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dtd1nrob1" checked="@(Model.dtd1nrob == "1" ? true : false)" name="dtd1nrob" value="1">Não realizada por óbito em data anterior</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dtd1nrob2" checked="@(Model.dtd1nrob == "2" ? true : false)" name="dtd1nrob" value="2">Não realizada por outro motivo</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Onde estão as questões do seu formulário?

Comment: E no que precisa ajuda? Ao selecionar o `checkbox` não deveria desativar todo o formulário? O que deveria acontecer quando você "volta" ao formulário? E o mais importante, se os checkbox funcionarão como radios, por quê não usa os radios? Detalhe: você não está escapando devidamente os caracteres nos eventos "checked" dos inputs.

Comment: como que voce "volta" pro seu formulario?

Comment: Só uma observação: você tem dois checkbox com o mesmo name, mas não precisa declarar duas vezes o evento de change. Ele vai saber do que se trata numa chamada só.

Comment: Então eu não posso usar radio button, porque vai ficar travado nesta questão, esses dois checkbox desabilitam todas as questões do formulario, se nenhum deles estiver selecionado o usuario consegue preencher o formulario normalmente. Conseguiu entender ? @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Como é que nenhum dos dois vai poder estar marcado se eles devem atuar como radio buttons?

Comment: O problema é na hora do load, quando eu carrego a pagina eu queria que todas as opções venha desabilitadas

Comment: Qndo tu diz: todas as opções, o que é que são essas opções? Divs com textarea, checkbox... ?

Comment: @Aline Segue o exemplo que coloquei Executa o script e veja por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    verificarCheckbox();
    $('[name="dtd1nrob"]').change(function () {
        verificarCheckbox();
    });
});

function verificarCheckbox() {
    $(".todosOsOutrosElementos").show();
    $('[name="dtd1nrob"]').prop('disabled', false).attr('disabled')

    if ($("#dtd1nrob1").is(":checked"))
        $('#dtd1nrob2').prop('disabled', true).attr('disabled');
    else if ($("#dtd1nrob2").is(":checked"))
        $('#dtd1nrob1').prop('disabled', true).attr('disabled');

    if ($('[name="dtd1nrob"]').is(":checked"))
        $(".todosOsOutrosElementos").hide();
}
```

Substitua: $(".todosOsOutrosElementos").show()/hide() pelos seus elementos.