# If utilizando load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, load

eu tenho a seguinte função em javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Eventos();
  $('[name="dtd1nrob"]').change(function () {
        BloquearQuestao();
    });
});


function Eventos() {
    BloquearQuestao(true);
};

function BloquearQuestao(load) {
    load = load || false;

    if (!load) {

    }

    var value = $('[name="dtd1nrob"]:checked').val();
    if (value == '1') {
        $('[name="dtd1"]').prop("disabled", true);
        $('[name="dtd1"]').val('');
    } else {
        $('[name="dtd1"]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

A variável `dtd1nrob`é um checkbox que quando ela for selecionada desabilita e limpa a variável `dtd1`, quando eu seleciono a variável `dtd1nrob` e salvo o formulário até ai tudo ok,  mas quando eu volto no formulário, a variável `dtd1` não está desabilita porém a variável `dtd1nrob` está selecionada, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Pergunta parece bastante com esta: [If Load javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188404)

Comment: Então é a mesma praticamente só que eu fui fazer os testes hoje e não resolveu, ainda  continua vindo desabilitados

Comment: O que é `load`? Como você chama a função `BloquearQuestao`?

Comment: atualizei o topico

Comment: Faça `console.log(value)` dentro da função `BloquearQuestao` e veja os valores que estão sendo considerados.

Comment: está retornando o valor 1 name="dtd1nrob" value="1"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55067/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-leonardo-macedo).

Comment: Ok, já estou lá!

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver o meu problema coloquei todas as funções dentro do document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Eventos();
  $('[name="dtd1nrob"]').change(function () {
        BloquearQuestao();
    });

function Eventos() {
    BloquearQuestao(true);
};

function BloquearQuestao(load) {
    load = load || false;

    if (!load) {

    }

    var value = $('[name="dtd1nrob"]:checked').val();
    if (value == '1') {
        $('[name="dtd1"]').prop("disabled", true);
        $('[name="dtd1"]').val('');
    } else {
        $('[name="dtd1"]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
}

});
```